# xslt adding constant number of siblings

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a large number of files with a structure like the following a.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="a">aaa
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11
          <div class="e">eee11</div>
          <div class="f">fff11
            <div class="g">ggg111</div>
            <div class="g">ggg112</div>
            <div class="g">ggg113</div>
            <div class="g">ggg114</div>
            <div class="g">ggg115</div>
            <div class="g">ggg116</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d">ddd12
          <div class="e">eee12</div>
          <div class="f">fff12
            <div class="g">ggg121</div>
            <div class="g">ggg122</div>
            <div class="g">ggg123</div>
            <div class="g">ggg124</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">ccc2
        <div class="d">ddd21
          <div class="e">eee21</div>
          <div class="f">fff21
            <div class="g">ggg211</div>
            <div class="g">ggg212</div>
            <div class="g">ggg213</div>
            <div class="g">ggg214</div>
            <div class="g">ggg215</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- The number of div class="c" is variable in each file (zero or more)
- The number of div class="d" is variable inside each (zero or more)
- The number of div class="g" is variable inside each (zero or more)

I would like to have a number of div class="c" equal to the max_c parameter in all files.

I use the following shell script to pass the max_c parameter with a value equal to 3:

```
#!/bin/bash
xsltproc --param max_c 3 a.xslt a.html
```

And I use the following a.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="max_c"/>

 <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='a']" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='b']" />
   <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='c']" />
   <xsl:call-template name="AddC">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$max_c - count(div[@class='c'])" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="AddC">
  <xsl:param name="count" />
  <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
   <div class="c">ccc
   </div>
   <xsl:call-template name="AddC">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is the following:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div class="b">bbb</div>
      <div class="c">ccc1
        <div class="d">ddd11
          <div class="e">eee11</div>
          <div class="f">fff11
            <div class="g">ggg111</div>
            <div class="g">ggg112</div>
            <div class="g">ggg113</div>
            <div class="g">ggg114</div>
            <div class="g">ggg115</div>
            <div class="g">ggg116</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d">ddd12
          <div class="e">eee12</div>
          <div class="f">fff12
            <div class="g">ggg121</div>
            <div class="g">ggg122</div>
            <div class="g">ggg123</div>
            <div class="g">ggg124</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">ccc2
        <div class="d">ddd21
          <div class="e">eee21</div>
          <div class="f">fff21
            <div class="g">ggg211</div>
            <div class="g">ggg212</div>
            <div class="g">ggg213</div>
            <div class="g">ggg214</div>
            <div class="g">ggg215</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="c">ccc$count</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is almost what I would like, with 2 exceptions:

1. The first div has lost its class="a" and its value aaa
2. The added div class="c" should have a value of ccc3, and not ccc$count

What am I doing wrong?

As usual I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please only choose relevant tags. Your question is not about [tag:xquery], XQuery is not even supported by the tool you're using.

Comment: Is your XSLT missing something, as it currently only outputs `ccc` and not `ccc$count`?

Comment: Sorry, new to this site and very new to xslt, xquery, xpath, etc. I've seen your notice only now. Thank you, I've taken notice and went through my posts to correct all tags as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The first div has lost its class="a" and its value aaa*
To add the missing attributes and text content change the `xslt:copy` like the following:

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | div[@class='b']  | text()" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="div[@class='c']" />
```

The  `@*`adds all attributes and the `text()` all text content.

*The added div class="c" should have a value of ccc3, and not ccc$count*
change the output for div c as:

```
<div class="c">
   ccc<xsl:value-of select="$count"/>
</div>
```